# Passing a prop from a Parent component becomes null in the Child component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a simple React site which fetches some data from an API ([this API](https://github.com/HypixelDev/PublicAPI)) and then display it on the page. The endpoint I am using is the `skyblock/auctions` endpoint. What this returns is a list of objects, which I want to get the first one of and then pass it to a child component. The parent can successfully get the data, however when I pass it to the child and `console.log` it, it returns `null`. The only reason I can think of for why its doing this is because the parent component hasn't finished fetching the data yet, but I am not sure how to make it render only after its finished.

Here is the code for the parent component `AuctionViewer`:

```
class AuctionViewer extends Component {
  state = { data: null}

  loadData = async () => {
    let url = "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions?key=INSERT_KET_HERE" 
    let response = await fetch(url);
    let json = await response.json();

    this.setState({data: json.auctions[0]}, function () {
      console.log(this.state.data)
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
    setInterval(this.loadData, 60 * 1000);
  }

  render() { 
    return (<Auction data={this.state.data} />);
  }
}
```

And here is the child component `Auction`:

```
class Auction extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,

    item: null,
    price: null,
    startPrice: null,
    time: null,
  };

  loadData() {
    let data = this.props.data;
    console.log(data);

    let end = new Date(data.end - Date.now());
    let timeLeft = end.getHours() + ":" + end.getMinutes() + ":" + end.getSeconds();     
    this.setState({loading: false, item: data.item_name, price: data.highest_bid_amount, startPrice: data.starting_bid, time: timeLeft, timestamp: end});
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="gridBox">
        {this.state.loading ? (
          <p>Loading...</p>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <p>Item: {this.state.item}</p>
            <p>Top Bid: {this.state.price}</p>
            <p>Start Bid: {this.state.startPrice}</p>
            <p>Time Left: {this.state.time}</p>
          </div>
        )}
        <button onClick={this.loadData}>Refresh</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The only reason I can think of for why its doing this is because the parent component hasn't finished fetching the data yet...

That's right.

> ...but I am not sure how to make it render only after its finished.

You have two options:

1. *(I don't think you want this one.)* Move the ajax call into the parent of the parent component, and only render the parent component when you have the data.
2. Have the parent component render a "loading" state of some kind until the data is available

#2 looks something like this:

```
render() { 
  const { data } = this.state;
  return (data ? <Auction data={data} /> : <em>Loading...</em>);
}
```

...but probably with something more attractive than just a `<em>Loading...</em>`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest was is with some conditional rendering while `AuctionViewer` is "fetching" the data. The initial state is `null` and this is passed to `Auction`, but you can conditionally render other UI or null while waiting.

```
render() { 
  const { data } = this.state;
  return data ? (
    <Auction data={data} />
  ) : <div>Loading...</div>;
}
```

Or return null to indicate to react that nothing should be rendered.

```
render() { 
  const { data } = this.state;
  return data ? (
    <Auction data={data} />
  ) : null;
}
```